# Setting the image position via code

Tags: c#, silverlight, image

I want to set the image position via code to fit on the button (see screenshot). But I can't work it out. In WinForms it was easy, but in Silverlight I can't just set the X & Y apparently.

```
 public void LockControls()
    {
        int LockIndex = 0;

        DependencyObject myUserControl = LayoutRoot;
        foreach (var button in FindAll<Button>(myUserControl))
        {
            if (button.Tag != null)
            {
                Image LockedIcon = new Image();

                LockedIcon.Width = 20;
                LockedIcon.Height = 20;
                //LockedIcon.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);


                LockedIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/LockedIconx20alpha.png", UriKind.Relative));
                LockedIcon.Name = "Lockie" + LockIndex;

                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(LockedIcon);
                button.Tag = "Locked" + LockIndex;
                LockIndex++;

            }
        }

    }
```

http://puu.sh/wS7g
THe screenshot shows the image position (the locck), but I don't understand how the current position is being set. Just to clarify, I want to set the position to the "0%" button

Thanks in advance,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to set the Image position arbitrary, you should host the Image control in a Canvas container.

However, in your case you should really change the Content element of your Button depending on the need for showing the lock or not.

```
<UserControl  DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}} 

        <Grid.Resources>
            <converters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Button Width="100" Height="23" IsEnabled="{Binding IsControlsEnabled}">
            <Button.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="lock.png" Margin="10,0,10,0"
                           Visibility="{Binding IsControlsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Button"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

Additionally, you shouldn't really write the kind of code you have in your question in Silverlight. Learn how to use data binding. It's very powerful. Simply bind the `IsEnabled` property of your Buttons to an exposed Property instead.

An example of doing so using the MVVM Light toolkit (I recommend you learn the MVVM pattern for Silverlight/WPF development):
The View Model:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

  private bool isControlsEnabled;
  public bool IsControlsEnabled
  {
    get { return isControlsEnabled; }
    set
    {
      if (IsControlsEnabled.Equals(value)) return;
      isControlsEnabled = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsControlsEnabled);
    }
    }
}
```

The Visibility Converter:

```
 public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return (bool)value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

And then you can simply enable/disable all controls that are bound, for example using a CheckBox:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsControlsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Controls are enabled"/>
```

Comment: I found out that the position it has now, is the center of the window. But I want to set the position via code not via XAML, since the image is generated in runtime

Comment: Well, I think the method you are using is inferior. It's very inefficient to manually iterate to controls, find their position, manually add images the layout and positioning them on the page. Learn how to use data binding in Silverlight. It's very very powerful and blows away the need for writing code like the method you have in your question.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way of doing. If I understand correctly you want to super-impose an image on top of a button to prevent the user from using it. It won't work.

For that you have to understand the [layout system of Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645025%28v=vs.95%29.aspx): the controls are laid out by the engine during the measure and arrange events.
Trying to overlay an image like that will require you to hook up on those events, or derive the Button class and override the Arrange method to overlay your image.

But that won't prevent the user from using the button because the button itself is not disabled, and one could just "tab" into it, and activate it.

Instead I suggest you use a style for the button, and override, say, the Disabled state to overlay your locked image. [The button style is described here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
All you have to do is replace:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
```

by

```
<Image x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" Width="20" Height="20" Source="images/LockedIconx20alpha.png" />
```

And set the opacity in the following to 1:

```
  <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
      <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".55"/>
      </Storyboard>
  </vsm:VisualState>
```

Set this style on your button (I assume you know how to do this) then when you need to lock your button, set it to disabled and your image will be automatically laid on-top and your button will be un-clickable.